# Unable to get node-webkit code

Tags: git, chromium, node-webkit

I am created node-webkit directory and created a .gclient file as shown [here](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Building-node-webkit). I also did all the setting for depot_tools and others. Running `gclient sync` gives me error :

```
remote: Counting objects: 2024928
remote: Counting objects: 2068705, done.
  No output for 30 seconds from command:
    git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g clone --no-checkout --progress --template
=C:\CEF\depot_tools\depot_tools\git-templates https://github.com/zcbenz/chromium
.git C:\CEF\node-webkit\_gclient_src_kxm4fo;  cwd=C:\CEF\node-webkit
remote: Compressing objects:  18% (71703/378108)
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (378108/378108)
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (378108/378108), done.
Receiving objects:   2% (45097/2068705), 15.07 MiB | 1.06 MiB/s
Receiving objects:   2% (45945/2068705), 15.32 MiB | 16 KiB/s
Receiving objects:   2% (46211/2068705), 15.39 MiB | 6 KiB/s
Receiving objects:   2% (46480/2068705), 15.47 MiB | 4 KiB/s
fatal: early EOF
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: index-pack failed
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\CEF\depot_tools\depot_tools\\gclient.py", line 1804, in <module>
    sys.exit(Main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "C:\CEF\depot_tools\depot_tools\\gclient.py", line 1794, in Main
    return dispatcher.execute(OptionParser(), argv)
  File "C:\CEF\depot_tools\depot_tools\subcommand.py", line 245, in execute
    return command(parser, args[1:])
  File "C:\CEF\depot_tools\depot_tools\\gclient.py", line 1590, in CMDsync
    return client.RunOnDeps('update', args)
  File "C:\CEF\depot_tools\depot_tools\\gclient.py", line 1152, in RunOnDeps
    work_queue.flush(revision_overrides, command, args, options=self._options)
  File "C:\CEF\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient_utils.py", line 755, in run
    self.item.run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\CEF\depot_tools\depot_tools\\gclient.py", line 627, in run
    self._used_scm.RunCommand(command, options, args, file_list)
  File "C:\CEF\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 151, in RunCommand
    return getattr(self, command)(options, args, file_list)
  File "C:\CEF\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 357, in update
    self._Clone(revision, url, options)
  File "C:\CEF\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 879, in _Clone
    if os.listdir(tmp_dir):
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\CEF\\nod
e-webkit\\_gclient_src_kxm4fo/*.*'
```

When i do git --version from command line it gives `1.8.1.msysgit.1`.

When i go to the `depot_tools` git directory and check it gives `1.8.0.msysgit.0`.

Also depot_tools are at the last in my path system variable PATH.

What should i do ?

Comment: Any success in playing AVI files?

Answer (score 0):

The connection of your "git clone" command broke unexpectedly. You can try to clone that repo manually or find a better network connection.

Comment: so i should clone https://github.com/zcbenz/chromium manually and depencies in its .DEPS.git only ?

Comment: Does it mean download zip files ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all Repositories in [.DEPS.git](https://github.com/zcbenz/chromium/blob/node/.DEPS.git). And you can follow [this](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/891) to manually clone them.